# MS Ribbon for WPF - How can I change the skin

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I'm using the latest version of MS Ribbon for WPF (3.5.40729.1). 
Downloaded from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2BFC3187-74AA-4154-A670-76EF8BC2A0B4&displaylang=en and want to change the skin of ribbon.
How can I change the skin ?
Is microsoft planning to provide any skins in the next release?
Thanks for the help.

Regards,
Vishal.

Answer (score 1):

Sample from southridge labs:

```
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="Southridge.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary">

  <r:RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Blue.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </r:RibbonWindow.Resources>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

Comment: This works for the Office UI Ribbon. There is a new ribbon release from Microsoft. Link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2BFC3187-74AA-4154-A670-76EF8BC2A0B4&displaylang=en. Your code will not work with the latest ribbon release.